# Build the first order signature

Tags: first-order-logic

This is a homework question, and my mind is working a little backwards today. So I'm asking for help on a easy question, so that I can unravel the harder ones on my own.

How to create the first order signature with formula "z is GCD of (x and y)
 or LCM"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"z is GCD of (x and y) or LCM"

Let's break this into smaller part. It means that $(z\:\text{is GCD of}\:x\:\text{and}\:y)\lor(z\:\text{is LCM of}\:x\:\text{and}\:y)$.

The phrase $z\:\text{is GCD of}\:x\:\text{and}\:y$ means $z$ divides $x$ and $y$ and that $z$ is the smallest such one. Hence, $(z|x)\land(z|y)\land(\forall d:((d|x)\land(d|y)\implies d|z))$. We can break it smaller knowing that $(a|b)$ is also $(\exists n:b=an)$.

Then we just substitute all this into the initial phrase.

You should know where to stop to obtain your first order signature (which I do not know to be honest).